# Python commandline argument doesn't print

Tags: python, arguments, sys

I'm trying to collect variables from the command line arguments with this script

```
import requests
import json
import sys, getopt

UNKNOWN = -1
OK = 0
WARNING = 1
CRITICAL = 2
usage = 'usage: python artifactory-move.py -u/--user -p/--password '

def command_line_validate(argv):
  try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, 'u:p', ['user=' ,'password='])
  except getopt.GetoptError:
    print (usage)
  try:
    for opt, arg in opts:
      if opt in ('-u', '--user'):
        try:
          user = arg
        except:
          print ('***user value must be an entered***')
          sys.exit(CRITICAL)
      elif opt in ('-p', '--password'):
        try:
          password = arg
        except:
          print ('***password value must be entered***')
          sys.exit(CRITICAL)
      else:
        print (usage)
    try:
      isinstance(user, str)
      #print 'user level:', user
    except:
      print ('***user is required***')
      print (usage)
      sys.exit(CRITICAL)
    try:
      isinstance(password, str)
      #print 'password level:', password
    except:
      print ('***pass is required***')
      print (usage)
      sys.exit(CRITICAL)
  except:
    sys.exit(CRITICAL)
  return user, password

argv = sys.argv[1:]
user, password= command_line_validate(argv)
print (user)
print (password)
```

Can't find the reason why the it only prints user, I suspect it's the first "try" but i'm not sure how else to do this. I'm new to python perhaps i'm missing something very obvious here

Comment: Why not catch the exception and print it? You're throwing away useful information.

Comment: Any reason not to use `argparse`?

Comment: I didn't know about argparse, this works for me now but i'll definitely still check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

```
opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, 'u:p', ['user=' ,'password='])
```

**The u:p means:**

-u take an argument (because ':' after u)
-p take no argument (no ':' after p)

Hope this will help you

Comment: Yep that was it! Thank you, I didn't even notice that.